# Please help me with this icon that is next to my singnal strength icon,which is round with a minus like line.

Tags: internal-storage

Please help me ,its urgent. I shall be indebted to you for life. Thanking you.i have never seen this icon. It appeared after a few months after updating my phone to android marsmallow 6.0.1. Is it a malware,trojan,virus icon? If so then pls help me to remove it.

Comment: Based on how you describe it, the icon seems to be the one for the **"Do Not Disturb"** notification mode.

Comment: It might help to [edit] your post and include a screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "Restricted" (aka. "Do not") system icon on Lollipop mean?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/98431/what-does-restricted-aka-do-not-system-icon-on-lollipop-mean)

Comment: Juni: Can you please take a look at the screenshot in the linked question and let us know whether it's the same icon you're seeing? The one looking like a "no parking" sign? Does the behavior match?

Answer (score 0):

As Death Mask Salesman said, it's the icon for the `Do not disturb` feature.You can toggle it on and off by swiping down from the top bar. You can customize your notification rules during the 'Do not disturb' mode, from `Settings -> Sound and Notification -> Do not disturb`.